# Some of the hidden $_POST Vairables failing to display within internal iframe

Tags: php, variables, post, iframe, session-variables

I am new to coding and have learned a whole lot in the last 12 months using S/O so i would like to say thanks for helping me out and any input is more than appreciated.

I have created a 4 page Registration form that consists of the following process:
1.  index.php  (Main page / Landing page with form input values)
2.  page2.php  (Select date, time and confirm appointment)
3.  page3.php  (Booking confirmed please Select nearest location, Survey and service)
4.  SSL Payments page with iframe insert from 3rd party

on page3.php i have inserted an internal iframe that is hosted on the same server, using separate css files, js, ect.. So due to my lack of coding skills i found it easier to insert the iframe rather than merging the page as 1 complete page.

Now on all pages i have managed to get the $_POST Variables passing from page 1 --> 2 --> 3
But on page 3 i fail to get all the variables displayed in the iframe hidden inputs. I can not understand why only some are being displayed and others are not.. When the form gets submitted the only ones that come through are the ones you can see hidden in source code.

i have also tried to do the following:

insert `<?php session_start();?>` at the top of the page

and at the bottom of page i have:

```
<?php
        $_SESSION['Name']=$_POST['Name'];
        $_SESSION['Postcode']=$_POST['Postcode'];
        $_SESSION['Building']=$_POST['Building'];
        $_SESSION['EmailAddress']=$_POST['EmailAddress'];
        $_SESSION['Telephone']=$_POST['Telephone'];
        $_SESSION['datepicker']=$_POST['datepicker'];
        $_SESSION['timeofsurvey']=$_POST['timeofsurver'];
        $_SESSION['PropertyOwner']=$_POST['PropertyOwner'];
?>
```

I have these on each page to make sure they get passed across each page, All the input ['names'] are correct and on the same page where the iframe is they are displayed back to the user in a text box to the right side of the iframe basically to show the user that their information is correct while booking their appointment.

Here is my iframe form source code:

```
<div id="app" my-app my-controller="Controller">
    <form action="Processing.php" id="regForm" name="regForm" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['Name'];?>" name="Full Name">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['Telephone'];?>" name="Telephone">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['EmailAddress'];?>" name="Email">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['Building'];?> " name="Building Number or Name">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['Postcode'];?>" name="Postcode">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['PropertyOwner'];?>" name="PropertyOwner">    
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['datepicker'];?>" name="Survey Date">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['timeofsurvey'];?>" name="Survey Time">
```

The only hidden variables failing to display are the following:

```
['Name']
['EmailAddress']
['datepicker']
['timeofsurvey']
```

All other variables are being displayed fine, As i said even the page that has the iframe inserted is also displaying all variables back to the user correctly. If you click to view page source code you see them fine... Then as soon as you view the inner iframe source code you see the variables above are missing.

This is the outcome when viewing the iframe source code:

```
<div id="app" my-app my-controller="Controller">
<form action="Processing.php" id="regForm" name="regForm" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="Full Name">       **<----- This input is missing**
<input type="hidden" value="0123456789" name="Telephone">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="Email">       **<------- This input is missing**
<input type="hidden" value=" " name="Building Number or Name">
<input type="hidden" value="NW1 1AA" name="Postcode">
<input type="hidden" value="Yes" name="PropertyOwner">    
<input type="hidden" value="" name="Survey Date">       **<--- This input is missing**
<input type="hidden" value="" name="Survey Time">       **<--- This input is missing**
<input type="hidden" name="field_passthrough1" value="Consumer" />
<input type="hidden" name="field_passthrough2" value="en-UK" />
```

I hope i have not gone the longest way round here trying to explain, as i understand a lot of you guys are really to busy to be reading long posts like mine when it will be something so simple.. I have spent 2 days trying all sorts to get this working and i can not seem to get a way round this.

I would really appreciate any help guys, Thank You.

#############  UPDATE TO LAMONDE ################

This is how i now have the iframe and the only fields that are now missing is:

```
['Name']
['EmailAddress']
['Building']
```

--->  ['datepicker'] and ['timeofsurvey'] are now working...

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['Name'];?>" name="Name">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['Telephone'];?>" name="Telephone">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['EmailAddress'];?>" name="EmailAddress">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['Building'];?> " name="Building">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['Postcode'];?>" name="Postcode">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['PropertyOwner'];?>" name="PropertyOwner">    
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['datepicker'];?>" name="datepicker">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['timeofsurvey'];?>" name="timeofsurvey">
```

Here is source view on page3.php iframe:

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="Name">
<input type="hidden" value="07541258585" name="Telephone">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="EmailAddress">
<input type="hidden" value=" " name="Building">
<input type="hidden" value="saas" name="Postcode">
<input type="hidden" value="No" name="PropertyOwner">    
<input type="hidden" value="21/01/2015" name="datepicker">
<input type="hidden" value="4:30 pm" name="timeofsurvey">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $_POST will have the same name has your input.

So: $_POST['Name'] != $_POST['Full Name'];

It's pretty much the same for every input that are missing.

Also you really shouldn't use spaces in input names

Comment: I saw your whole post, my answer is correct about it. 

You're setting $_POST['Name'] to $_SESSION['Name'], but $_POST['Name'] don't exist because your input name is: 'Full Name' and not 'Name'

Comment: on index.php the oringal input variable is:                            <input name="Name" type="text" required="required" class="first" id="Name" placeholder="Name" value="" maxlength="100" />  This is also correct for "EmailAddress" and "Building"  All other pages have the exact same code as i posted above and all pages are displaying the hidden variables apart from iframe. The iframe is inserted in page3.php under where the user can view what he has already inserted so for example here is the code that page3.php returns back to the user...

Comment: <li><strong>Name:  <?php echo $_SESSION['Name'];?>
                </strong></li>                  <li><strong>Building Name/Number:  <?php echo $_SESSION['Building'];?>
                </strong></li>                <li><strong>Email:  <?php echo $_SESSION['EmailAddress'];?>
                </strong></li>

Comment: In your iframe, the input name is Full Name, so when you POST it, you your $_SESSION['Name'] will be emptied, because your hidden input name is: Full Name and not Name (so $_POST['Name'] == NULL when it comes from your iframe).

Comment: I have updated my initial post above if you would like to view that as i have changed the iframe hidden input code to what you suggested and managed to get datepicker & timeofsurvey working.. i think i have followed what you said but not sure if i have, so hopefully from viewing the code you will see if im wrong again. also i changed the session = post to this at the bottom of the page:  
<?php
        $_SESSION = $_POST;
?>   and removed all the rest of it

Comment: Try to see with: var_dump($_POST); and var_dump($_SESSION); to see why you lose informations. That should make the debugging process a lot easier.

Comment: Solved..... :) :) :)   I can not +1 you because i do not have +15 rep yet!! the problem was not with page3 or with the iframe, it was page2.php and both yourself and Dalija was correct as page 2 hidden variables was like this:      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST["Name"]; ?>" name="Full Name">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST["Telephone"]; ?>" name="Telephone">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST["EmailAddress"]; ?>" name="Email">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST["Building"]; ?>" name="Building Number or Name"> ... More to come...

Comment: Changed the names in page2.php to match with page3 input like you said:  name="Building Number or Name" should be the same as $_SESSION['Name'];  Changed name="full name" to "Name", email to "EmailAddress" and building name or number to "Building" and everything works perfectly now from page 1 to page 3 including iframe.. Thanks for your help i really appreciate it :)

Comment: P.S... I only found out from using the var_dump as you said :)